# How can I enter some text in a keyboard macro that uses helm mode?

Tags: helm, keyboard-macros

I want a keyboard macro that does something like this:

1. Call `org-refile`
2. Insert two characters(In this case `''`)

So whenever I invoke the keyboard macro, it lets me enter some other text, but saves me the fact of entering `''` every time I use it.
The problem is that I try to stop recording the keyboard macro after entering those 2 characters, but helm doesn't allow me to do it. Then, if I try to edit the keyboard macro to something like this: (I've remapped org-refile to F7)

```
(fset 'interesting-name
   [f7 ?\' ?\'])
```

But I think it adds a `RET` at the end, because it doesn't allow me to enter text, and refiles the subtree to the first result in the helm minibuffer.
I hope there's a way to do this, maybe it's a simple fix and I don't get it, thanks for reading.

Comment: Hope this question is clear to someone else. It's not clear to me (so far).

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but just want to show some empathy. I used Helm for a while and loved everything about it except two things: it made startup really slow (which I didn't really care about since I used the server/client setup) and I couldn't use it in macros. Switching from Helm to ivy solved both problems (at the cost of some wonderful functionality, such as doing file operations from within helm-find-files).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-interactive way to do it:

```el
(defun auto-org-refile-helper ()
  (insert "''")
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'helm-helm-commands-helper))

(defun auto-org-refile ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'helm-helm-commands-helper)
  (call-interactively #'org-refile))
```

I'd love to see a less hacky method, but I doubt you will find one that works interactively.